# Unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection refused)

Tags: php, ios, ssl

I have a problem, I'd like to send out push notifications using php, however I keep getting this error:

```
Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection refused) in /home/colupon/public_html/iPhone/push/index.php on line 21
Failed to connect: 111 Connection refused
```

My code is as follows:

```
$deviceToken = '0f************************************************************78';

$passphrase = '************';

$message = 'My first push notification!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
$filename = 'ckdev.pem';
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $filename);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'default'
);

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . 

$payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered'.PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);

?>
```

I believe the problem is with the server I'm using because I posted the same code and the same .pem file on a different server and it sent the notification without any problem. I attempted to open up ports on the firewall for my server because I read that might cause this problem, but the same error message still showed up. Is there anything else I can do? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 15):

This issue is common problem in Apple Push notification, to resolve this error you have to go through as follows:

1. Test your pem files locally and remotely in server if the problem is server go to 2 else build pem correct file.
2. Set up the permission wrong on the folder that had the certificate file. This worked for me:

> chmod 755 your_folder_that_has_certificate_files

3.Check connectivity of apns port 2195 from your hosting server as follows:

run

```
 telnet gateway.push.apple.com 2195
```

if this is the problem

```
Trying 17.172.233.36...
telnet: connect to address 17.172.233.36: Connection refused
```

you can solve this issue by opening the port 2195 on the production server. You can verify by following command $telnet gateway.push.apple.com 2195

```
-bash-3.2# telnet gateway.push.apple.com 2195

Trying 17.149.38.141...
Connected to gateway.push.apple.com (17.149.38.141).
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: How do I telnet from my hosting server? I am using godaddy. The servers usually do allow telnet to their server but not from their server to another. If you could shed some light on this that would be great. Currently APN is working if I run it locally but when i upload the files to godaddy hosting i get connection refused error.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this Saad? I'm in the exact same situation. Thanks.

Comment: ^the other way is like this,make a temp link of your server like this 192.4.3.xx/~username/foldername/filename hit thats it

Comment: Hi @SaadBashir I'm having the same issue with godaddy. were you able to solve it?

Comment: @SaadBashir facing same issue. Have you find any solution

Comment: In my case port was disabled on server

Answer (score 2):

In case of **MAC**,
(built-in server was working fine using terminal but not through browser, for me, so i installed MAMP.)

1.Go to---> **/Library/WebServer/Documents**/----copy both **php** and **ckdev.[pem](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)** file here.

2 go to **terminal**-->**$open /private/etc-->go to--->apache2>originals>httpd.config file-->
**"#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so"**, remove "**#**"..(perhaps, you would have to change the permission also..!)

then goto browser and check--> localhost/yourPhpFile.php

In Case of **Windows system**,

1.Install **WAMP**,

2.goto **php.ini** file--->search for this "**;extension=php_openssl.dll**" line and remove semicolon "**;**".

3.click WAMP icon from right-bottom goto **PHP>PHP Extensions>select php_openssl**..

That's it..hope this may help further seekers.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that I forgot to setup my passphrase correctly in php script.

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = 'xxx';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'xxx';
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, it was the SELinux issue.

So in your /etc/selinux/config file, set the **SELINUX=enforcing** to **SELINUX=disabled**. And restart. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the SAME error and I found the solution for my problem.

`‚mypassword‘` instead of `'mypassword'`

Seems like notepad changed the quotes. This literally took me 4 hours...  Hopefully someone will read this and save some time...